# Loop to generate divs and populate them from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a mysql nightmare. Let me explain my problem.

Here is what i'm trying to achieve: !http://i604.photobucket.com/albums/tt125/TheNameHobbs/client_workoutpage_example.png

I have a table in a database populated with different workout machines. I need this loop to make a div for each machine in the database and put the picture in along with the link. The database has a machine id along with machine name, image path, and link to video.

This is what i have to create the divs:

```
function machine_count() {
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`machine_id`) FROM `machines` WHERE `machine_id` = $machine_id"), 0);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $machinecount = machine_count();
        for (var i = 0; i < $machinecount; i++) {
            $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'div' + i,
        'class': 'some_class_name',
        'html': 'i am div with id=div' + i
        }).appendTo('.body1');
        }
        });
```

CSS:

```
.body1 {
width: 100%;
}
.some_class_name {
width: 24.5%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Somehow i need to add in that loop a way to grab the machine picture and link and populate them accordingly for each div.

Any ideas?

Comment: `mysql_query` and `mysql_result` are PHP functions, not Javascript.

Comment: You're mixing up PHP and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Combine your `JQUERY` and `PHP` code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `machines` WHERE `machine_id` = $machine_id";
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
        {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
            $('<div/>', {
                    'id': 'div _<?php echo $row["machine_id"]; ?>',
                    'class': 'some_class_name',
                    'html': 'i am div with id=div '+ 
                            '<?php echo $row["machine_id"]; ?>'+  
                            ' <?php echo $row["machine_name"]; ?>'+
                            '<img src="PATH_TO_IMAGE/<?php echo $row["image_name"]; ?>" /> '+
                           ' <?php echo $row["video_link"]; ?>'
                }).appendTo('.body1');

    <?php   } ?>

});
```

Comment: and $conn is the connection to the database?

Comment: For some reason i get "Could not get data"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this,using jquery or using PHP. If you want to use php use below script..

```
 <?php
  $i=0
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT `machine_id`, `IMAGE_PATH`. `video_link` FROM `machines` WHERE `machine_id` = $machine_id")
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
    <div id= "<?php echo $i; ?>"  class= "some_class_name"> i am div with id=div <?php echo $i; ?>>
     <img src="<?php echo $rows[IMAGE_PATH]; ?>" alt="" />
     <a href="<?php echo $rows[video_link]; ?>">Video Link</a>
    </div>
    <?php $i++; }  ?>
```

Comment: The image path and link are also coming from the database

Comment: I modified the things just use this..it will help you...and if you need count...please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up PHP and javascript.

try this instead:

```
//PHP CODE
<?php
function machine_count() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`machine_id`) FROM `machines` WHERE `machine_id` = $machine_id"), 0);
}
?>

//JAVASCRIPT CODE
$(document).ready(function() {
    $machinecount = <?php echo machine_count(); ?>
    for (var i = 0; i < $machinecount; i++) {
        $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'div' + i,
        'class': 'some_class_name',
        'html': 'i am div with id=div' + i
        }).appendTo('.body1');
    }
 });
```

Make sure that your file has the php extension and that you're running it on a server.

Comment: `Make sure that your file has the php extension and that you're running it on a server` this make me laugh

Comment: Yeah i just forgot to add the php tags. Still don't know how to populate the divs with the pictures though

Comment: Ok so you are make the difference between PHP and jQuery? The problem is from your MYSQL statement. Instead of returning the count, you need to return the data. All of this should be done directly in php.

Answer (score -1):

I finally came up with this solution:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

<?php

    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `machines`"), 0);
for ($machine_id = 0; $machine_id <= $count; $machine_id++) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `machines` WHERE `machine_id` = $machine_id";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
        $('<div/>', {
                'id': 'div _<?php echo $row["machine_id"]; ?>',
                'class': 'some_class_name',
                'html': '<img src="client workout page/round_<?php echo $row["machine_id"]; ?>.jpg" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;"><br>'+ 
                        '<img src="<?php echo $row["picture"]; ?>" style="width:50%;display:block;margin:0 auto;"/> '+
                       ' <a href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>"><img src="client workout page/click to play video.jpg" style="width:186px;height: 14px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></a>'
            }).appendTo('.body1');       
<?php   }
    }
 ?>

});
</script>
```